# Unable to Output Data to text file

Tags: windows, powershell, output

I am using the following script to pull a list of all my computers from my wsus server.  It then places then in a neat list and this works fine.

However, when I try to output the data to a text file it creates the text file but writes no data.  Is there something I am missing in the Output part? Full script below.

```
$wsus = 'halvedge2'
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration") | Out-Null
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer()
$wsus.GetComputerTargets() | Select FullDomainName, LastReportedStatusTime, LastSyncTime

out-file -filepath "\\halvedge2\c$\PS1\WSUS\Last installed Update\updates.txt"
```

Additionally I would like to add an If statement to it looks at the LastSyncTime and for any LastSyncTime over 30 days it only returns them Computer Targets.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to out-file separately:

If the below yields value, then Instead of this:

```
$wsus.GetComputerTargets() | Select FullDomainName, LastReportedStatusTime, LastSyncTime
```

Do This:

```
$wsus.GetComputerTargets() | Select FullDomainName, LastReportedStatusTime, LastSyncTime | Out-File "D:\updates.txt" -Append -Force
```

Note: First try saving locally. If it works, then try remotely on the UNC. If remote fails, then give permission to the specific user to save it.

Comment: @DeanY: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciable